# No rule to make target '.oppfeatures', needed by 'src/inet/features.h

Tags: build, omnet++, inet

I am using OMNet++ 6.0.1 and  [inetmanet](https://github.com/aarizaq/inetmanet-4.x) and I was trying to run the TestNetwork simulation but it failed to build. Here is the error:

> make MODE=release all  make: *** No rule to make target
> '.oppfeatures', needed by 'src/inet/features.h'.  Stop.
> "make
> MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be
> incomplete.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `.oppfeatures` in the inetmanet root folder. That file is part of the distribution and required for the build.